# Body of html document is not extending past a div unless i remove floating property of the div(s)

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to set the layout of my page into three section by floating each of the section left according to the device width with the help of media queries in my css. I have succeeded in doing so although when I try to inspect the page using chrome developer tool I can confirm my body is not spanning across the section(s). On removing the `float` property from the media queries the body element is spanning as desired though my layout would not be designed as desired as all section are  in a block which is not desired. Is there an explanation for the behavior or how would the problem be corrected? Below is a link of the jsfiddle page for the page https://jsfiddle.net/nma71c4w/. Thank you as you help me in the problem.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <section>
       <div class="hidden-element">
            <h2 ></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="title-element">
            <h2 > Chicken</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
             my contents
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

The css style causing the error is around media queries like.

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
        .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col- 
         lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12{
            float: left;
                                   
        }
        ....
}
```

Comment: That is the normal behavior of float, the element gets taken out of the document Flow as if it doesn't exit, and if the parent of that element only has it then the parent's dimensions becomes 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `overflow: hidden;` to the *container*  of those floated elements (in your case the `body`?) in order to make it wrap all floated children which it contains. This seems like a strange thing, but it's a common way to solve that problem.

Comment: This answer is most useful. Thanks @Johannes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of media query you can use grid property in css.

```
<div class="main">

       <div>
            <h2 ></h2>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h2 > Chicken</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
             my contents
            </p>
        </div>
   
</div>
```

css:

```
.main{
display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr));
}
```

That should solve your problem. If you dont understand what grid is, I recommend you to watch these :
https://youtu.be/t6CBKf8K_Ac

It is more powerful and useful.